# ListView inside SingleChildScrollView: RenderBox was not laid out

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have a horizontally scrollable container and inside it somewhere a ListView, which scrolls vertically:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    primary: false,
    itemCount: 5,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return const SizedBox(
        height: 10,
        width: 10,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

but I get this error: `RenderBox was not laid out`. I already put `Expanded` around everything imaginable. It has to be a `SingleChildScrollView`.

I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide width on `ListView`, it will solve the issue.

```dart
LayoutBuilder( /// needed to be top level
  builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
      child: ListView.builder(
        primary: false,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
            width: 10,
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, //you may get different way like LayoutBuilder on top level
    child: ListView.builder(
      primary: false,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
          width: 10,
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: That looks promising, could you post the option with the layout builder as an answer please?

Comment: added, just make sure not to put `LayoutBuilder` inside scrollable widget. Else it will get infinite size(depend on direction)